# Enable OneDrive for Business auto backup of Desktop, Documents and Pictures with registry

Tags: onedrive

Just wanted to post this incase it helps someone else in the future, for companies that don't have intune. Registry edit to enable OneDrive for Business backup of Desktop, Documents and Pictures.

Comment: If you're asking and answering in the same post, you should post the solution (the registry stuff) as an answer instead of part of the question. Also, I think this would be more appropriate on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign into the Onedrive account and also get your tenant ID out of Azure AD. Once in Azure AD, go to Properties in the left menu and your tenant ID is listed. You need to put that ID into YourCompanyTenantID. Registry keys below to enable:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\OneDrive" /v KFMSilentOptIn /t REG_SZ /d YourCompanyTenantID /f REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\OneDrive" /v KFMSilentOptInWithNotification /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\OneDrive" /v KFMSilentOptInDesktop /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f Reg ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\OneDrive" /v KFMSilentOptInDocuments /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\OneDrive" /v KFMSilentOptInPictures /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

After running registry file on multiply PC's. Onedrive was enabled and syncing after restart of PC.